# Un Hilo a la espera de todos los otros - Java Thread

Tags: java, hilos

espero que me puedan ayudar con un problema que tengo hace varios días y necesito una solución ya que es para una entrega importante.
En resumen lo que quiero hacer es tener un Hilo principal "HiloReloj" que por cada instante/señal mande a ejecutar a todos los otros hilos para que cumplan sus tareas. Pero no puede volver a mandar otra señal hasta que todos hayan terminado su trabajo.
He intentado de varias maneras y no lo he conseguido, hasta pensé que hacer un contador de notify() pero no tengo muy clara la idea de como hacerlo.
De antemano, gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mostranos lo que hiciste y donde falla.

Comment: Sin código no podemos ayudar